# Webpack Hot Reload Infinite Refresh in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, react-boilerplate

I'm having a strange hot reloading issue that I think is related to my environment, but I can't track down what is. I was hoping someone else had run into it and could point me in the right direction. I've been banging my head on this one for a couple days now.

I'm running dev webpack locally (Mac) that comes bundled with `react-boilerplate` with hot reloading enabled. Anytime a changes is picked up by webpack it rebuilds and then infinitely fetches the `*.hot-update.json` file causing the page to infinitely refresh.

Logs from server:

`0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: webpack building...
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: webpack built 665bc020ab09de31dd8e in 372ms
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /static/7dd032a1be4383284dfd.hot-update.json - 0
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /static/1.7dd032a1be4383284dfd.hot-update.js - 1
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /static/1.7dd032a1be4383284dfd.hot-update.js.map - 0
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /perk/6 - 148
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /static/7dd032a1be4383284dfd.hot-update.json - 0
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /perk/6 - 142
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /static/7dd032a1be4383284dfd.hot-update.json - 0
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /perk/6 - 138
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /static/7dd032a1be4383284dfd.hot-update.json - 0
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /perk/6 - 139
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /static/7dd032a1be4383284dfd.hot-update.json - 0
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /perk/6 - 138
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /static/7dd032a1be4383284dfd.hot-update.json - 0
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /perk/6 - 141
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /static/7dd032a1be4383284dfd.hot-update.json - 0
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /perk/6 - 141
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /static/7dd032a1be4383284dfd.hot-update.json - 0
0|web-clie | 2018-02-07 00:30 +00:00: 200 GET /perk/6 - 142`

`"webpack": "3.5.5",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.1",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "1.11.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.0",`

webpack config: https://gist.github.com/cgray9/0333b4b4278da06a17395c7967ca489a

dev middleware: https://gist.github.com/cgray9/0333b4b4278da06a17395c7967ca489a

Note: This issue is only occurring in Chrome. HMR works fine in Safari.

I've tried uninstalling Chrome and deleting all of it's Applications files with no luck.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: I've got the same issue. Have you got the solution?